# Java pipe and filter pattern issue

Tags: java, object

I have a `List<Animals>`

```
public class Animals{
    int legs; 
    int age;
    int eyes;
//getters , setters 
}
```

I want to perform different operations in any combination on the list. E.g. calculate mean, calculate median, calculate middle value of two fields and so on.

In the particular case where i want to calculate the `median` based on the middle value of `Animal legs` and `Animal age`, how is this done?.

i would first have to loop though the arraylist and peform (legs+age)/2 to get the middle value. I would then feed these value to the next operation that would calculate the mean. So my question is, where do i store the data performed in the first operations, in order to pass it to the second?. Is it possile to dynamically extend the Animal object to contain a new field?. I was thinking that i can create a temporary array and store the results but then i would lose information about the animal and there would be no mapping either.

(i know how to calculate the mean/median and so on, just want to know how to approach this problem to parse the data correctly)

Answer (score 0):

You could either extend `Animals` for methods working only on `Animals` fields to calculate the middle value of an animal (pro: you have a meaningful name for your operation. contra: your class grows in size) or create a (temporary) `Map<Animals, Double>` of `Animals` to middle values and traverse the map afterwards to calculate the mean value (pro: your class doesn't grow in size, contra: you have a meaningful name for your operation).

Comment: But what happens when you have to stack up several more operations on top of it? You will have a very large Map<> that will be troublesome to iterate though it. Also adding another variable inside the class woulden't suffice - if in the future i want to extend this so it works with any object, i would have to extend all the objects too

Comment: Why should it be troublesome to iterate a `Map`? And I don't talk about "adding another variable" but to add a method `getMiddle` or something, which calculates the middle value on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you store data in containers and do not add to existing classes. You only want to break this rule if you have a very good reason to do.

Let's take a look at some containers:

- `List<Animal>`: Simply a list, you cannot add any extra information to it
- `Map<Animal, X>`: A map that maps an `Animal` to a specific datatype. Here `X` can be a  direct value such as a `Double` (note that it needs to be an object, not a primitive), or a custom class in which you can store multiple data fields.
- `Map<Animal, List<X>>`: A map that maps an `Animal` to a list of specific datatypes.

These are the most important data types and they generally offer great performance with `ArrayList` and `HashMap`.

Comment: ok, so what happens in the case that i need to sort the Map<Animal,x> based on x?. How would this be done

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 that would be:

```
Double[] vals = animals.stream()
        .map(animal -> (animal.getLegs() + animal.getAge()) / 2.0)
        .sorted()
        .toArray(Double[]::new);
double median = (vals.length % 2 == 0) ? (vals[vals.length / 2]  + vals[vals.length / 2 - 1]) / 2: vals[vals.length / 2]
```